# Shield UI Condtional Item Colorization Based on Series

Tags: shieldui

I'm using an ASP.NET bar chart with multiple series, and was wondering how to apply a separate set of conditional item colorization to each series.  For example:

```
protected void ShieldChart1_SeriesItemDataBound(object sender, ChartSeriesItemDataBoundEventArgs e)
    {
        ChartSeriesItem item = e.Item as ChartSeriesItem;

        // If Series A, use these colors:

        if (item != null)
        {
            int value = (int)item.ValueY;
            if (value < 20)
            {
                item.Color = Color.Green;
            }
            else if (value > 55)
            {
                item.Color = Color.Yellow;
            }
            else if (value > 60)
            {
                item.Color = Color.Orange;
            }
            if (value > 75)
            {
                item.Color = Color.Red;
            }
        }

        // If Series B, use these colors: ...

    }
```

Thanks in advance,

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You may find useful this demo with complete source code:

https://shieldui.com/search/content/item.Color

I think it gives idea of how to do what you are intending and also there are some additional sources you may find interesting.